# Bathtub faucet leaking

Tags: plumbing

My bathtub faucet tends to leak more then normal when i pull the lever to turn on the shower head.
Please refer to photo for detail
As you can see it still leaks more then normal, after I had pulled up the lever for the shower head. It didn't normally do this, it just started to happen and I'm wondering if this is an easy fix or do I need to replace the spicket?

[image]

Comment: It is not clear to me that you have what I would call a leak. These diverters do not seal perfectly. Are you saying that when the water valve is on and the diverter is set to deliver water through the shower head that some water is dribbling out of the spigot? If so, this is not much of a fault. On the other hand if water is dribbling out of the spigot when the water valve is off, so water is dribbling out *all the time* that is a different matter--that is a leak. Which do you have?

Comment: Also, after showering right after you turn off the water if you leave the diverter in the shower position, water will dribble out of the spigot for some time until the water in the piping drains down. This is also not  a leak. To shorten this dribbling time just push the diverter valve down to the spigot position after (or before) turning off the water at the valve.

Comment: It's only when the water valve is turned on. There's almost a delayed reaction when I pull the valve to turn on shower. Normally there wasn't any delay once I pulled the valve, the shower came right on. What's happening now is the spigot will continue to pour water (after the valve has been pulled) then a few seconds later the shower will come on. My guess would be the pull lever valve isn't closing the water coming out of the spigot

Comment: I have a diverter valve in the wall and so I don't have direct experience with this type of diverter, but I think it may be possible to renew the seal and even to renew it in place without unscrewing the spigot. I suppose (but don't know) that one unscrews the pull lever and a tab or disc drops out and you would change a seal. It sounds to me like the seal has come loose and the water pressure forces it against the sealing orifice. BUT THIS IS JUST A GUESS.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases there may be a gasket or o-ring that may have cracked or fallen out. In other cases replacing the whole spigot may be the only option, unless you can actually get a replacement part for just the diverter assembly that actually fits your particular spigot.

It's often quite difficult to figure out exactly what model you have, which makes searching for parts rather difficult. The ones I have personally fixed, I replaced the whole spigot.

Comment: ditto.  The spigot is not expensive and nearly trivial to replace (usually a set screw underneath).

Comment: Thanks I kinda figured that replacing the spigot would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The site below shows the different possible types of tub/shower diverter spout. https://www.familyhandyman.com/plumbing/faucet-repair/how-to-replace-a-bathtub-spout/view-all